# CSS background image using :after only shows when on hover

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an anchor element with the class `.et_pb_button` and the following CSS (SASS):

```
.et_button_no_icon .et_pb_button {

    &:after {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 30px;
        content: "";
        background: url("images/boton_rojo.png");
        width: 28px;
        height: 27px;
        margin-top: 2px;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the image only shows on hover. See the link here: http://oasysgp.kevinmamaqi.com/ (the anchor is Nuestras Empresas, below the first parragraph).

I would like to display the image in normal and on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.et_pb_button:after` there is a `opacity: 0;` and I found a `.et_pb_button:after display: none` in your css style. Sadly you haven't uploaded your source maps so I cant see on which line this is. But disabling the display:none, and disabling the opacity: 0; did the trick for me.

Comment: The opacity: 0 was the problem. I didn't saw it and is not on my code (I'm modifying a theme). Thank you.

Comment: No problem, editing a theme can always bring some tricky problems with it. Happy I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the background image for this code as default .et_button_no_icon a.et_pb_button {... }